# telling if key exists in mysql table is taking too long

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, query-optimization

I started with this question: [is my large mysql table destined for failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612361/is-my-large-mysql-table-destined-for-failure)

The answer that I found from that question was satisfactory.  I have a table with 22 million rows that I would like to grow to about 100 million.  At this time, the table `minute_data` structure is like this:
[image]

A problem that I am having is as follows.  I need to execute this query:

```
select datediff(date,now()) from minute_data  where symbol = "CSCO" order by date desc limit 1;
```

Which is very fast ( < 1 sec ) when the table contains the value "CSCO".  The problem is, sometimes I will query for a symbol that is not in the table already.  When I execute a query like this for, say, symbol = "ABCD":

```
select datediff(date,now()) from minute_data  where symbol = "ABCD" order by date desc limit 1;
```

Then the query takes a LONG TIME... like forever ( 180 seconds ).

A way I can get around this is by making sure that the table contains the symbol I am looking for before I execute the query.  The fastest way I found to do this is with the follow query, which I just need to use to check to see if the table `minute_data` contains the symbol I am looking for or not.  Basically I just need it to return a boolean value so I know if the symbol is in the table or not:

```
select count(1) from minute_data where symbol = "CSCO";
```

This query takes over 30 seconds to return 1 value, way too long for my liking, since the query above, which actually returns a `datediff` calculation only takes less than 1 second.

`symbol` column is part of the pri key, I thought it should be able to figure out if a value exists there very quickly.

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a fast way to do what I want to do?  Should I change the structure of the data to optimize performance?

Thank You!

**UPDATE**

I think I found a good solution to this problem.  From the answer below by LastCoder, I did the following:

1) Created a new table called `minute_data_2` with the exact same definition as `minute_data`.

2) 
    ALTER TABLE minute_data_2 ADD PRIMARY KEY (symbol, date);

3)
    INSERT IGNORE INTO minute_data_2 SELECT * FROM minute_data;

4)
    DROP TABLE minute_data;

5) Rename minute_data_2 to minute_data

Now I am seeing blindingly fast speed for the same query which I described above as taking more than 180 second, now completes in .001 seconds.  Amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using EXISTS (...)

```
select datediff(date,now()) from minute_data  
where EXISTS(SELECT * FROM minute_data WHERE symbol = "CSCO") 
AND symbol = "CSCO" order by date desc limit 1;
```

Even though symbol is a primary key, it seems you have the timestamp as a PK as well which makes me think you are using a COMPOSITE pk which means the ordering is by timestamp then symbol. You may want to put separate index on symbol, if all you have is a composite one where timestamp is first.

Comment: Yes I did try the `EXISTS` query, which has performance the same as the query I mentioned above... it takes about 30 seconds for this one: `select EXISTS(SELECT * FROM minute_data WHERE symbol = "ABCD");`.

Comment: You are right, my PK is composite on (date, symbol).  Would it make a difference if it was defined as (symbol, date), putting `symbol` first?  I can also try the index on symbol.

Comment: he means you should add an index on symbol only

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind - if most of your queries have a finite symbol clause (either 1 symbol or a IN(list_of_symbols) you would be best served to put the symbol column first in your composite key. Adding an index on just the symbol column is kind of a (it's running slow so...) hacky solution but would work as well.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I think switching the order of the primary key is the right idea also.  I have successfully removed the old primary key settings from the table, but I am having a hard time setting the new primary key.  I use the query: `alter table minute_data add primary key (symbol, data)`, and each time I get an error: `2031: Lost connection to MySQL server...` after about 600 seconds, even though it is on local host.

Comment: Looks like that might be a MySQL workbench issue, i will try from the command line.

Comment: @LastCoder -- Holy Sh**!  That query that took 180 seconds yesterday now completes in .001 seconds.  This is unbelievable!

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind - difference between a b-tree search and a full table scan.

Answer (score 0):

I think is better to make a table named `symbols` and add a reference to that table in your `minute_data` table:

**symbols**:
symbol_id (INT, Primary Key, Auto Increment)
symbol_text (VARCHAR)

**minute_data**:
key_col (BIGINT, Primary Key, Auto Increment)
symbol_id (INT, Index)
other_field

Use InnoDB as table type for adding references.

Try to avoid duplicate entries into your tables..

Comment: That does not seem to address my issue, since i need date/symbol combinations to by unique in the minute_data table.